# php how to view class variable in script?

Tags: php

the class, which is content.php

```
class content
{
    private $vars = array();

    public function set($var, $var_value)
    {
        $this->vars[$var] = $var_value;
    }
```

index.php file using the content class

```
include 'content.php';
$instance = new content();
$instance->set(image_dir, '/images/');
include 'display.php';
```

display.php

```
<?php

echo '<img src={image_dir}/graphic.gif width=556 height=49></td>"';
```

How do I use the content->var variable in the display.php? which is the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a getter.

```
class content
{
    private $vars = array();

    public function set($var, $var_value)
    {
        $this->vars[$var] = $value;
    }

    public function getImageDir()
    {
         return $this->vars['image_dir'];
    }
}
```

And then:

```
include 'content.php';
$instance = new content();
$instance->set(image_dir, '/images/');
$image_dir = $instance->getImageDir();
include 'display.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a getter to your class:

```
class content
{
    private $vars = array();

    public function set($var, $var_value)
    {
        $this->vars[$var] = $var_value;
    }

    public function get($var)
    {
        return $this->vars[$var];
    }

}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
$instance->get(image_dir);
```

Note that if image_dir is not a constant IE. `define('image_dir', '../images/blah');` then it should be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a get() method in your class?

```
public function get($var)
{
    return $this->vars[$var];
}
```

Maybe you can have a look to the magic method __call() too

Answer (score 1):

just do in content class:

```
public function getVar(){
   return $this->vars;
}
```

and in index.php

```
echo '<img src='.$content->getVar()['image_dir'].'/graphic.gif width=556 height=49></td>"';
```

Comment: This won't works, except for PHP 5.4 (unfortunately, I still have to wait to use it :( )